# What causes AirDrop receiving to be so slow?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, airdrop

macOS Big Sur 11.6 MacBook Pro 2015 receives AirDrop soooo slowly.

My iPhone 7 received the video files from a friend in a few seconds. My MacBook Pro took upwards of minutes to see progress in the loading bar, and then just fails not receiving anything.

Now I am trying to send the video files from my iPhone 7 to my macbook. Normally this is very fast, normally AirDrop is very fast between my iPhone and my MacBook I've never had problems before, but today it's taking hours.

What could be causing this? How can I make my MacBook receive AirDrop faster?